# Asynchronous HTTP POST in C# 4.0

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I've used the following code to perform asynchronous HTTP request in C#.

```
    private static Task GetUrl(string url)
    {
        var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        request.UserAgent =
            "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/30.0.1599.69 Safari/537.36";
        request.Accept = "text/html";
        return Task
            .Factory
            .FromAsync<WebResponse>(request.BeginGetResponse, request.EndGetResponse, url)
            .ContinueWith(t =>
            {
                if (t.IsCompleted)
                {
                    using (var stream = t.Result.GetResponseStream())
                    {
                        using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
                        {
                            //Console.WriteLine("-- Successfully downloaded {0} --", t.AsyncState);
                            //Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadToEnd());
                        }
                    }
                }
                else if (t.IsFaulted)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("There was an error downloading {0} - {1}", t.AsyncState, t.Exception);
                }
            });
    }
```

However I'm not sure how I should modify the above code to support HTTP post as well. Any help is appreciated!

In particular I'd like to know how I should add BeginGetRequestStream and EndGetRequestStream into the current function...

Comment: Just search for "WebRequest POST", it's pretty simple and [here's](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/debx8sh9.aspx) a link...  it has nothing to do with the rest of your code, you just need to configure your `WebRequest` differently.

Comment: Please see this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18513907/how-to-make-multiple-post-request-using-httpwebrequest-in-silverlight-4-and-net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Method property of the HttpWebRequest:

```
request.Method = "POST";
```